# Grouping products by categories with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to group products by category. Consider the following two models:

```py
class Category(BaseModel):
    title = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False, unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Category({})".format(self.title)
    
    
class Product(BaseModel):
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'), nullable=False)
    category = db.relationship("Category", backref="product")
    title = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
    amount = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    status = db.Column(db.Enum(ProductStatusEnum), nullable=False, default=ProductStatusEnum.stock)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Product({})".format(self.title)
```

```py
@app.route('/')
def index():
    products = Product.query.filter_by(status=ProductStatusEnum.stock).all()
    return render_template('index.html', products=products)
```

The desired result:

- Drink

  - Milkshake
  - Tea
- Food

  - Burger
  - Hotdog
- Sweet

  - Soufflé

How can I prepare a query with SQLAlchemy and show it?